# Symlink - how to create symlink with Git

Tags: git, directory, symlink

I need to create symbolic link in my web pages. There is public folder called `data`. It would be great if I could create symlink from this folder to external folder out of my web application. There are stored data for downloading.

1. Is required to make the `data` folder?
2. When I push it to remote repo, does it work in each of clones after
   fetching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symlink as such is just recorded by `git`. Its target does not have to exist. Whether or not it works when you check out the repo also depends on the capabilities of the systems where you check it out (some file systems don't permit symlinks at all, for example).